# How to get the number of times a piece if word is inside a particular column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'll try to use a simple example to describe my problem.

I have a csv file with many columns. One of this columns' header is "names".

In this column "names" I need only the times the name "John" is repeated.

As an example, my column "names" is as follows:

```
names
John
John M
Mike John
Audrey
Andrew
```

For this case I would need a python script using pandas to get the value of 3 because the word 'John' is repeated three times.

These are the codes I am using:

```
from_csv = pd.read_csv(r'csv.csv', usecols = ['names'] , index_col=0, header=0 )

times = from_csv.query('names == "John"').names.count()
```

But it only returns me 1, because there is only one row that has only John.

I have tried using:

```
times = from_csv.query('names == "*John*"').names.count()
```

but no success.

How can I get the 3 for this particular situation? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `str.contains`

```
df.Name.str.contains('John').sum()
Out[246]: 3
```

Or we using `list` and `map` with `in`

```
sum(list(map(lambda x : 'John' in x,df.Name)))
Out[248]: 3
```

Comment: @ananvodo yw : -) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.Series.str.count` to count the number of times in each row a pattern is encountered.

```
df.names.str.count('John').sum()

3
```

In this example, it matches OP's output.  However, this would produce different results if `John` appeared more than once in one row.  Suppose we had this `df` instead:

```
df

                 names
0            John John
1        John M John M
2  Mike John Mike John
3        Audrey Audrey
4        Andrew Andrew
```

Then my answer produces

```
df.names.str.count('John').sum()

6
```

While Wen's answer produces

```
df.names.str.contains('John').sum()

3
```